# enable Submit button on ckeditor validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>CKEditor</title>
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
<textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" onkeyup="val()"></textarea>

<input type="button" name="next" value="Submit" id="nxtbtnwht1" disabled/>

        <script>
                 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                   function val()
                    {
        
                    var a = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();

        
                        if(a!==null || a!==""){
          
                        document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = false;
                       }
                      else
                     {
                       document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = true;
                      }    
                }  
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I have ckeditor 4 in one page. On page, submit button is by default disabled I want to put validation on ckeditor4 textarea on check whether it is empty or not if it is empty put button as disabled and if some text is in ckeditor textarea then button should be visible. So How can I Do it with Javascript?

Ckeditor Textarea code:

```
<textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" onchange="val()"></textarea>
```

Submit Button Code:

```
<input type="button" name="next" value="Submit"  id="nxtbtnwht1"  disabled/>
```

Javascript code:

```
function val()
  {
    
    var a = CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();
    
    
    if(a!==null || a!==""){
     
    document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = false;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Hi ! Please check run code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this.

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {});
editor.on("pluginsLoaded", function(event) {
  editor.on('contentDom', function(evt) {
    var editable = editor.editable();
    editable.attachListener(editable, 'keyup', function(e) {
      if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData() == "") {
        document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = true;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nxtbtnwht1").disabled = false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.19.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea cols="10" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" onkeyup="val()"></textarea>

<input type="button" name="next" value="Submit" id="nxtbtnwht1" disabled />
```

Comment: Hi that's working for only for simple textarea functionality but not working for ckeditor

Comment: In your ckeditor HTML code, you need to add [id="editor1"] and [onkeyup="val()"]. Do you have this two in your ckeditor HTML code?

Comment: Hi I have provided run code snippet . Can you please check that code . give me suggestion according to that?

Comment: I already modify my answer. You can try.